# Is there a way to substitute a text that has regex formatted number ranges and replace with all combinations?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, count, search-replace

Let's say I have a file that looks like:

```
host[1-2]lx
host[1-4]win
```

what I want is an easy way to get

```
host1lx
host2lx
host1win
host2win
host3win
host4win
```

Is there a neat way to automate that process?

Edit: What I was hoping for is something like using a substitution on `host[1-4]win` using the line number, where I can repeat the replacement using the `[1-4]` part. Imagine something like

`:110s_host\[1-4\]win_host1win\rhost2win\rhost3win\rhost4win\r_`

But is there a way to not spell out the four hosts, instead have sed repeat it based on what was found in the `[...]`?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Regular expressions work the other way around. They match existing strings, they don't generate them. Also, all you want is a tiny subset of regular expressions; i.e. you don't want to extend `.*`. Overall, this sounds more like a task for a scripting language than for an editor. If you run into problems scripting a solution, ask on SO. I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @romainl I had not tried much because I don't even know where to start. So far I had been doing it by making N number of copies manually, and then using the line numbers in a substitution. For example. if the N is at the end, and the line numbers are 112 to 116, I would remove the sqr brackets stuff and do `112,116s/$/\=line('.')-111/`

Comment: @Friedrich, oh gotcha, thanks. Makes sense I guess. I somehow assumed there has got to be a Vim way of doing this easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt a simple solution exist for any regular expression but for you case you could:

Define the following function:

```
function! GenerateLineRange(start, end, i1, i2)
    let ret = ''
    for i in range(a:i1, a:i2)
        let ret = ret . a:start . i . a:end
        if i != a:i2
          let ret = ret . "\n"
        endif
    endfor
    return ret
endfunction
```

Use it in a substitution:

```
:%s/\v(.*)(\[(\d+)-(\d+)\])(.*)/\=GenerateLineRange(submatch(1), submatch(5), submatch(3), submatch(4))
```

Comment: Oh wow, that is extraordinary, it works! Thank you so much! And it is very readable, I get it. Never seen a Vim function before, so I just learnt something massive. Thanks again!

Comment: One question, what is the `\v` in the beginning?

Comment: @deedarhuq `\v` turns on *very magic* mode, see `:help /\v`. It's used to type fewer backslashes to escape special characters.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Welcome to Vim ;-)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! VivianDeSmedt and @Friedrich